# Excel How to insert value based on todays date

Tags: excel-formula

I have 4 columns in excel. Date, Apple, Banana and Oranges. I have a different sheet where I have a header called "Today's Production" Under the header I have Banana, Apple and Oranges listed. How do I populate these fields 
[Screenshot added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWlKm.jpg)

Comment: Hi, could you have a read of this page please [MCVE].  At the moment I think the best answer, based on the info given, would be - select the cell and type "Banana".

Comment: Thnx Darren for pointing out, my bad, sorry. I have attached the screenshot for reference please. Hope this helps understanding my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first cell of your table were in A1, for the bananas column, you can just use something along the lines of

```
=SUMIFS(B1:B10,A1:A10,TODAY())
```

Then for apples, you would adjust your B column to C, and for oranges, adjust B to D